# Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider an $m\times n$ matrix over a field $K$, $A\in M(m, n, K)$. The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$ is a matrix $A^+\in M(n, m, K)$ such that,

$AA^+A=A$

$A^+AA^+=A^+$

$(AA^+)^*=AA^+$

$(A^+A)^*=A^+A$

For $x\in M(m, 1, K)$, let $A|x$ denote the matrix obtained by appending $x$ after the last column of $A$. Given two column matrices $u,v\in M(m, 1, K)$, is there a clear relationship between $(A|u)^+$ and $(A|v)^+$?

I realize the notion of "clear relationship" is vague, but any sort of algebraic identity relating to two, or evidence of no such identity would be extremely useful. I have not found literature in either case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from $(A\mid u)$ to $(A\mid v)$ is a special case of a "rank-1 update" which is expressed generally as a relation between a matrix $A$ and $(A + cd^T)$. There is a formula for the rank-1 update of the Moore-Penrose which says that $(A + cd^T)^+ = A^+ + G$ where $G$ is a certain matrix too complicated to write here. It can be found (with proper references) in Section 3.2.7 of the "[Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274)" by Kaare Brandt Petersen and Michael Syskind Pedersen.

This will work for matrices from $\mathbb{R}$. I am not so sure about other funny/fancy fields.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only for such a relevant answer but for the wonderful resource included.